# Haskell: IO confusion with Ints

Tags: haskell, io, int

Hey so I am trying to learn haskell and im running into trouble writing a program that requires me to collect Ints from the user in the terminal. how would i do this ive tried things like this

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)


getArguments :: IO Int
getArguments =
    do putStrLn "Enter the number of arguments you want to have"
       arguments <- getChar
       return (digitToInt arguments)


main :: IO()
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome to Random Argument Generator"
    let x = getArguments
    print x+1
```

but this does not work plz help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you don't allow the user to enter a number that's more than one digit long?

Answer (score 6):

replace `let x = getArguments` with `x <- getArguments`

the type signature for `getArguments` is (correctly) `:: IO Int`, which means that `Int` is 'wrapped' inside the IO monad, which means that you *have to* use the `val <- func` syntax to unwrap it.

*If* `getArguments` were a pure function (`:: Int`) the let syntax would have been correct.

Comment: Another problem is in the `print x+1` which should be written as `print (x+1)` or `print $ x+1`

Comment: TY! some of the tutorials ive been looking at are case specific and it is hard to derive what I need to do